# How to call another HTML file using swipe.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe, swipe.js

using SwipeJS how can I call a different html? For example using the following code to swipe pages I use it as index.html and I want to call other three inside like page1.html page2.html and page3.html Is that possible?

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div class="page">
      Page 1
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      Page 2
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      Page 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean to dynamically load content into the the .page div's?

Comment: Yes, so when I load index it will load the content from page 1. when I swipe will load page 2

Comment: swipe.js is just a slider. you'd need to do the loading part yourself. either through an ajax call, or load the content on the server